# RDLC how to sum values from child group?

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc

Got second issue:

My table structure in rdlc report looks something like this:

```
           |   BookCount   |
|Library1  |   [Value]     |
|City1     |   62          |
|Filial1   |   45          | 
|Filial2   |   17          |
|City2     |   40          |
|Filial3   |   40          |
```

Data grouped by Library names. Then it is grouped by Cities.

By Using `=SUM()` I received book count in each city, but now I need to sum Cities bookcount (Instead of [Value] there must be 102), and I don't know how to do it (with function help I could, but only if I needed to show values below table). I can't just sum because of expression.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the value outside of the row group.
[image: RowGroups]
In the image above, a `sum()` in the highlighted cell will sum all values for the `LibraryRowGroup`. A `sum()` in the cell above will sum all values for the `CityRowGroup`.

For example, with your data example, the highlighted cell will give you `Filial1` value. The cell above will give you `City1` value. If you add another row above that, outside the row group, it will give you the value for all data irrespective of Library or City. This will be the same as either summing all cities together or summing all libraries together - the total value in your dataset.

For your expression, you can use this:

```
=iif(sum(Fields!Active.Value) <= 0, 0, (sum(Fields!Active.Value) - sum(Fields!Taken.Value)) / sum(Fields!Ordered.Value))
```

Comment: I get it, but I updated my question just for this, because it was misleading. I got BookCount not by BookCount field, but by expression inside sum. Its not hard to sum values If they are inside field (just like in your example, but what about expression...

Comment: what does your expression look like? Are you using the same expression for both Library and City?

Comment: In short it is ­`=IIF(Fields!Active.Value>0, SUM(SUM(Fields!Active.Value)-Fields!Taken.Value)/Fields!Ordered.Value, Nothing)`   for Filial, and exactly thin but inside SUM for City. For Library, that was my question, how it supposed to look for Library?

Comment: Updated my answer to include this expression.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no. This will not work. Its simply  mathematically wrong. It maybe works fine ONLY if `active` or `order` are never 0. In case if anything of them are, book count is 0.

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Can you provide sample data then?